# can I merge these 2 functions into one? (in the name of cleaner scripts...)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Built a website on Google App Script (for ref its on michelmoalem.com).
On page load I populate several vars with verious text blobs read from docs stored on google drive (CV, Biography etc) I use a pair of functions for each blob - on the JS script that - the first one (in this example loadEditor) runs the function getDocContent from the main code page (server side script) and on success feeds the resulting blob to the second function (loadCvData) that populates the var (cvEditing) with the aquired text.

```js
function loadEditor(fetchResults){
    google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler(loadCvData)
      .getDocContent('16rvULQudFCcdJOb32Qk7qqfOfWmTxJ7MPuQ_fZJhaf4'); 
      }

function (fetchResults2){
     cvEditing=fetchResults2;
      }
```

what I was wondering is how to populate the var within the first function eliminating the need for this 2 step solution...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps:

```
function loadEditor(fetchResults){
    google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler(function(data){loadCvData(data);let cvEditing=fetchResults;})
      .getDocContent('16rvULQudFCcdJOb32Qk7qqfOfWmTxJ7MPuQ_fZJhaf4'); 
      }
```

#### Explanation:

You need the [success handler](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#withSuccessHandler(Function)) in order to handle data coming from server-side via [google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run) and use it client-side, that's how Apps Script works. At most you can use an anonymous function in the success handler, instead of calling another function, but that's it.

Comment: Thanks once again for the help - that simplifies the script indeed even if it still has 2 functions. As I have not much  experience in coding I have to ask - can one function run 2 actions serially without wrapping the 2nd step in a sub-function? i.e. cant we add cvEditing=fetchResults after getDocContent and loose the withSuccessHandler line?

Comment: You would have to provide the getDocContent() to be completely clear and I didn't include any parameters in the anonymous function but I presumed you were returning something from the called function.

Comment: yes the called function returns the blob data... thanks once again

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Have now reduced it to .withSuccessHandler(function(data){cvEditing=data;})